# Is there any way to display both the source and designer views in Xamarin and/or Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

In Visual Studio, while working on WPF apps, you get the nifty, extremely useful option of displaying the WPF designer view (click and drag) and the source file for that view underneath it. It's even enabled by default, I believe.

This would be supremely helpful while working on Android apps.

After spending about thirty minutes clicking through menus in both Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio, I'm at a loss. Google searches just bring up people having problems with long load times for the designer, or missing buttons to switch between the two.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the designer itself. Although, there might be an extension for VS so you can have two tabs open side by side. So maybe have one open for the Designer and one for editing the source for it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron That seems like the only option right now. I'm going to see if I can't submit this as a feature request to the guys at Xamarin. Thanks for the reply.